# gatorskin tyres

Tags: tire

I wondered if anybody could shed some light? I am attempting to put 700x32c gatorskin tyres on to a hybrid rim but am really having trouble getting the last 15cm on to the rim. The tyres that I had on previously were 700x42c. Should these fit or am I just kidding myself?

Kind regards

Matt

Comment: Some tires are harder to put on then others, but it should fit. Checkout these questions/answers for some tips: http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/4602/how-to-get-a-very-tight-tire-back-on-the-rim  or  http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/1235/how-to-get-the-tyre-back-on-to-the-rim-easily

Comment: The last minute or so of http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=uNhLPXfd8FM#t=110s shows the technique.

Comment: Thanks gents, tyres are now on! You have been most helpful. :)